# ResultSet column value modified: random strings sometimes added to one result set column value

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, ojdbc

Random strings are sometimes appended to only one `ResultSet` column value which data type is `NVARCHAR2`. Random string is appended before and after the true value of the column as can be seen in the figure below (uppercase string in the middle is the value stored in the database). We use `Oracle database 11.2.0.1.0` and JDBC driver is `oracle: oracle-jdbc: 11.1.0.6.0-Production +`. It happens randomly and cannot be reproduced from Oracle SQL developer or PLSQL developer. Has anyone had similar problems?

```
public <E> E query(String sql, ResultSetHandler<E> rsh, Object... params)
    {
        PreparedStatement stmt = null;
        ResultSet rs = null;
        E result = null;
        Connection connection = null;
        long timeStamp = 0;
        try
        {
            //log.debug("sql: " + sql + "\nparams: " + toString(params) + "\nResultSetHandler: " + rsh);
            log.debug("sql: " + sql);
            connection = checkConnection();
            stmt = connection.prepareStatement(sql);
            this.fillStatement(stmt, params);
            timeStamp = timeStampBegin();
            rs = stmt.executeQuery();
            timeStamp = timeStampEnd(timeStamp);
            log.debug("elapsedTime: " + timeStamp + " msec");
            result = rsh.handle(rs);
        }
        catch (SQLException e)
        {
            ...
        }

        return result;
    }
```

[image]

Comment: Since we can't see the SQL statement, the code extracting the value from the `ResultSet`, or what the query produces when run directly outside of Java, what did you expect us to be able to do?

Comment: `ResultSetHandler` just maps attributes from `ResultSet`, `result = rsh.handle(rs);` As I said before, it is not possible to reproduce when running the same SQL query directly outside of Java.

Comment: Try the latest JDBC driver.